# in C how to pass local function variable value to another function and print value without errors

Tags: c, pointers, ubuntu, printf, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int give_options();

int give_options(){

    printf("===== MENU 1 =====\n");

    printf("> store new customer :\t\tenter 1\n");
    printf("> view a customer :\t\tenter 2\n");
    printf("> view all customers :\t\tenter 3\n");
    printf("> exit program :\t\tenter 4\n ");   


    int ipt = malloc(sizeof(int));
    scanf("%d",&ipt);

    return ipt;
}


int main(){
    int dec = give_options();

    printf("decision is: %d", dec);     


    getchar();
}
```

Ive started to code in C recently in Ubuntu
im trying to return the value a local variable of one function and have it passed to another
function. I have read that since local variables are assigned to stack the value will no longer
exist after function returns, and that I have to allocate memory in heap using malloc.

when I compile I get this warning:

```
initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
[-Wint-conversion] int ipt = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

when I adjust this to int ipt = (int)malloc(sizeof(int)); -I get:

```
warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
int ipt = (int)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

What is the correct thing to do here?

I'm also having trouble with scanf since I switched to coding in Ubuntu.
I tried a different way, trying to use pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int* give_options();

int* give_options(){

    printf("===== MENU 1 =====\n");

    printf("> store new customer :\t\tenter 1\n");
    printf("> view a customer :\t\tenter 2\n");
    printf("> view all customers :\t\tenter 3\n");
    printf("> exit program :\t\tenter 4\n ");   

    int* ipt; 
    ipt = malloc(sizeof(int));
    scanf("d",&ipt);

    return ipt;
}


int main(){
    int* dec = give_options();

    printf("decision is: %d", dec); 

    getchar();
}
```

compiling this gives me following errors:

```
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int **’ [-Wformat=]
  scanf("%d",&ipt);

warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("decision is: %d", dec);
```

which approach is right and which one works?

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(int))` return a pointer to allocated memory.  Why does code save a pointer to an `int` with `int ipt = malloc(sizeof(int));`?

Comment: `scanf("d",&ipt);`  --> `scanf("%d",ipt);` since `ipt` is a pointer (in 2nd example).

Comment: @JohnnyMopp `"d"` --> `"%d"`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks. I caught that already.

Comment: @kanr Returning a local variable is ok. What you shouldn't do is return a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: Note that `int* give_options();` is not a prototype for the function in C; it is only a declaration of the function that doesn't specify anything about the argument list (except it can't be a function that takes a variable number of arguments because those must have a prototype in scope with the ellipsis `, ...)` present).  If you want to specify a function that takes no argument, use `int* give_options(void);`.  As it stands, the compiler can't reject `give_options("Aldeburgh", "Snape Maltings");` as a call to `give_options()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return the value directly (without using pointers)

change

```
int* give_options();
```

to

```
int give_options(){
```

and

```
int* ipt; 
ipt = malloc(sizeof(int));
scanf("d",&ipt);
```

to

```
int ipt;
scanf("%d", &ipt);
```

also you can leave

```
int* dec = give_options();
```

as

```
int dec = give_options();
```

The functions return value is left in r0 when the function returns.
I just noticed that your first example already does this.  Are you just trying to learn pointers?

Comment: And maybe note that this relieves you of the need to include `free(dec);` somewhere in the calling function after the call to `give_options()`.